# Incorporate Unity with Source Generator - Unity does not pick up the generated code during compilation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

```
--------sofware version--------
Unity version : 2020.2.7f1
IDE : Rider 2020.3.2
--------sofware version--------
```

I am having problems when I am trying to incorporate Unity with Source Generator.

I am able to build a source generator and put the resulting analyzer in Unity, my IDE is able to pick up the generated code(syntax highlighting is working), however when unity compiles it it was not able to find the related code and hence give an compile error.
[image: screenshot, IDE is properly highlighted but error in Unity's console]

It seems [people are having similar problems](https://forum.unity.com/threads/source-generators-via-roslyn-analyzers-in-2020-2.1003386/) but was not able to find a solution. I tried to force Unity to use a newer version of Compiler(3.10) using [third party library](https://github.com/mob-sakai/CSharpCompilerSettingsForUnity/tree/main) but that doesn't seems to fix the issue either.

To the best of my understanding the issue seems to be the compiler Unity is using is outdated, but I would assume my hack of forcing it to use a newer version of compiler should have solved the issue if that's the case.

What is the reason that it the source generator is not working, and how could I get around this? I don't mind using hacks as the project is not commercial.

---

Update:

I tried to confirm that my analyzer was at some point running by writing to a file whenever the Source Generator runs. As I can see my file being written to the configured directory, I am assuming my Generator is used at somepoint.

However I couldn't see any generated source code within the `obj` folder of Unity. This is different from the behaviour comparing to when I run my Source Generator outside of Unity.

What could be the possible reason behind this?

---

Update 2:

For better clarity(thanks @david-ao for suggestion), I thought it might be helpful to include trimmed generated csproj(In Unity csproj is automatically generated, and hence I override the project generation process and added some of the necessary settings):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="Assets/Analyzers/NoobJet.Analyzer.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="3.10.0-1.final">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
      <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)..\..\Assets\GeneratedFiles</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am trying to achieve the following outcome with the above settings:

1. Referencing the analyzer when compiling
2. Output the generated file to the appropriate directory(I intentionally wanted it to be not within the `obj` folder)
3. Using `3.10.0-1.final` compiler.

In case if it helps, [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zBBmH) is the full generated csproj file.

Comment: Can you post the csproj of your source generator project?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

Source generators are a .NET 5 feature. Unity can't target .NET 5, so using the latest compiler isn't going to help you; notice [this note](https://github.com/mob-sakai/CSharpCompilerSettingsForUnity/tree/main#for-c-90-features-preview) in the GitHub repository that you linked to.

It's worth nothing that Unity doesn't even support .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 won't have LTS, so it's unlikely we'll see support for this in the near future.

Comment: Unity doesn't target .NET Core at all .. only .NET Framework 4.x

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the consumer of Source Generator(SG) seems to not have the requirement on the support for .net 5, instead it requires to developing environment for the SG itself to be at least .net 5 or above.

Comment: Do you mind providing source of your claim for "Using the SG analyzer requires .net 5"? As most of the things I can find online is states that building the analyzer requires .net 5 but using it only requires .net standard 2.0

Comment: e.g https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Comment: quote:
A Source Generator is a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly that is loaded by the compiler along with any analyzers. It is usable in environments where .NET Standard components can be loaded and run.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. Try passing your generator as an analyzer in [csc.rsp](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html): `/analyzer:MyAnalyzer.dll`

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I never know that this exist.

However this doesn't fix my issue, I am fairly confident that Unity did pick up my csc.rsp as I can see that the extra argument is written to one of the  Unity's Temp file, having said that I can't be absolutely sure that it does as I don't know if the said temp file is actually being used

Comment: What are my possible option at this point? Is there anything I am able to do from my side to see what exactly is happening when compilation happens?

Comment: I also updated my question, it doesn't add much details, but you might want to have a look

Comment: source generators are a C#9 feature

Answer (score 0):

Source generators are a **C#9 feature** and strictly linked to the compiler.

Update:

Can you add a reference to a pre compiled dll? You create the source generator on netstandard2.0 targeting c#9 so it is totally controlled by you.
If you  can tell unity that the referenced dll is an analyzer and you already managed to force a newer compiler that targets C#9 then you would be at least with the minimum requirements for this to work, then of course things are different in Unity so this could not be enough, but at least is necessary

End Update

I am not a Unity developer so I am not 100% sure if this suits your needs but I will show you what fixed things for me in VSCode and Visual Studio with a similar issue, **somehow source generators were running but the IDE complained**.

UPD: I added the whole content of my csproj to show what other references i needed to make everything work.

The source generator project must target netstandard2.0, but you have to explicit the language version as netstandard2.0 by default targets C#7.3

```
      <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <PropertyGroup>
         <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
         <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2">
           <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
         </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I used net5.0 and things worked but the ide complained, my understanding is that the IDE needs it to be 2.0 because it is seen as an analyzer.

My consuming project is a net5.0 so by default I have C#9 enabled, you should check your consuming project is using C#9 and references the project or the dll as an analyzer

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>use_generator</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\generator\generator.csproj"
    ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
    OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
  </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="3.9.0">
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

On top of that I had to close and reopen Visual Studio to catch the changes and I have to do it every time I change the source generator, the feature is working but tooling is still in the early stages

Comment: In Unity, csproj is auto generated and any change on it will be overriden, but I've already done something similar to your setup by overriding Unity's csproj generation proces.

I will update my question to include the trimmed generated csproj for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

I writing this in Aug 2022 and Unity supports sourcegenerators right now
and this is even documented on their website https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html